# Can I call 'get account info' in instruction in rust?

Tags: account, instructions

I'd like to get account info from pubkey of account in instruction method in rust.
like this,

```
// instructions.rs
fn instruction_method() -> Instruction {  
  let pubkey: Pubkey;
  let account_info = solana::get_account_info(pubkey);
}
```

Is it possible? I know that I can contain account info when calling program call in client. But I want to get account info in instruction method.

Answer (score 4):

The way the Solana runtime (dubbed "Sealevel") works is that you have to pass ALL accounts that you will access in an instruction as "context" to the transaction. That way, Solana is able to know ahead of time which accounts a transaction will access, both readonly and read/write, and drastically improve parallelism. It's one of the key factors why it can be the fastest smart contract blockchain in the world. However, it comes with the constraint that all accounts that will be accesses need to be passed into the transaction from the client. If you do that, you will have access to the account_info by default.

However, from having some random Pubkey in an instruction (that was not being passed in form the client via the context), you will not be able to get the account_info.

Comment: It doesn't work because it does against how solana transaction works.
Thanks a lot!